# Async Methods in HTML Helper in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, task-parallel-library

In a ASP.net MVC application we read text content from MongoDb which we are showing in razor views like this.

```
 <span>@Html.T("WelomeText")</span>
```

This calls a method with a s signature like this:

```
Task<string> GetLocalizedTextAsync(string key)
```

this method read asynchoronously from mongo db. In order to make the call synchronous the call looks like this

```
var result = GetLocalizedTextAsync().Result;
```

What is the best way to make a method synchronous for HTML Helper? Currently we are assumim that his method is related to  some hangs of the an asp application

Comment: Why do you need to make the method synchronous? It will only yield control back to razor once it completes, be it synchronous or asynchronous.

Comment: Because i can't await in razor views ,can I ?

Comment: Calling controller actions directly from the view is usually a design smell. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26283535/waiting-on-tasks-in-asp-net-webpages-razor-view) can help.

Comment: I know but this is given in a larger application where i curently can't change this design

Comment: Does MongoDB expsoe any synchronous API's?

Comment: no. i need at least one async action in order to get the result